# Next.js: ./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/amp-dev.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a very serious issue right now trying to use Next js. No matter what version I use, any time I try to run the `npm run dev`, I get the following error:

```
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/amp-dev.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:\Usersudbasili\Documents\Programming\Acumen Developers\myportfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js' in 'C:\Users\udbasili\Documents\Programming\Acumen Developers\myportfolio\node_modules\next\dist\client\dev'      
error - Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\udbasili\Documents\Programming\Acumen Developers\myportfolio\.next\fallback-build-manifest.json'Require stack:
```

This is literally right after running the create next app command, so I don't install any additional package. One thing realized though is that this error doesn't occur when I use the public folder on my window PC but when I use the user folder called `udbasili` I get the above error. I have been using next.js for a long time and this is the first I am seeing this error

Comment: Look for this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67698221/18330318

Comment: @TeshAych that cant be the issue because the app works perfectly well in the Public user folder but not the main user folder called `udbasili`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue
the problem was that my project files was in a folder beginning with "ud". My folder name was "udemy".
Renaming that folder or moving the project outside that folder solved the issue

Comment: This is almost an absurd issue, but it was the problem in my case as well... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you compare the paths, there is a missing '\' :

`C:\Users**\\**udbasili\Documents\Programming\Acumen Developers\...`

`C:\Usersudbasili\Documents\Programming\Acumen Developers\...`

A quick solution that I gave to this issue was to create the project on a different path. For example:

`C:\dev\myportfolio`

Comment: I changed the path  to "d/react-test/nextjs-app" and it works

Comment: Is there no other solution/way to fix the wrong path other than this workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Please head over to https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled

By disabling swc in `next.config.js` it will resolve your issue.

You can disable swc by adding:

```
  experimental: {
    forceSwcTransforms: true,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your autoimport included `'/dist/client/dev'` in the `'next/amp'` path.

Does it work if you `import { useAmp } from 'next/amp'`?

Comment: Where would you place  this import?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a devshell and that required me to run the 'npm install' from devshell itself, not IntelliJ editor terminal.